# Why std::set provides begin() and end() if we can not modify the set elements

Tags: c++, set

As the elements of the `std::set` are in sorted order and each element is  unique. Also we can't modify the elements of the `set`, then why the library provides the `begin()` and `end()` functions as we already have `cbegin()` and `cend()`.

Comment: The `c` iterator functions were introduced in C++11, getting rid of `begin` etc. on containers that don't support mutable iterators would have broken a lot of existing code.

Comment: You learn something new everyday. Retracting comment.

Comment: Of course there have to be `begin` and `end`, or do you never want to iterate over the set?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because if you removed these functions, you would not be able to use `std::set` in many places where a [Container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container) is expected. The most obvious one (to me)<sup>1</sup>:

```
for (auto x: mySet) { }
```

Would not be possible because the range-based for loop rely on `begin` and `end`, not `cbegin` or `cend` (§6.5.4/1.3).

One other example where this would pose a problem would be the [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin)<sup>2</sup> function, which, as you can see in the link, rely on `c.begin()` and not `c.end()`.

The basic idea is that you do not want `std::set` to have a different *interface* than the other standard containers.

<sup>1</sup> There are many places like that, this is just one example among others.

<sup>2</sup> Note that even `std::cbegin` rely on the `const`-overload of `c.begin()` rather than on `c.cbegin()`.

Comment: Not really a good argument, as both ` std::set` and `for (auto x : y)` are defined by the same Standard. The Standard could just have said that if the container lacks a `begin`, then `cbegin` would be used.

Comment: @MSalters I think the standard wants to have a consistent interface for all of its containers (as I said in my answer), and removing `begin` from `std::set` would break that (or there would have to be change on the Container concept, which would imply a lots of change for nothing). But that's all my opinion (retro-compatibility is probably also an reason, but I don't think it is the only one).

Answer (score 3):

`cbegin()` and `cend()` are add in C++ 11.  `begin()` and `end()` are the old way to access set and they are keep for retro-compatibility.

Comment: While that's more or less true, it doesn't answer the question. Generic code requires consistent interfaces, and `begin()` and `end()` are the most commonly used ways to get iterators into a container. Even if `cbegin()` and `cend()` had been around when `std::set` was designed, it would still have provided `begin()` and `end()`.